# Passing value up in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parent

I have a component with a lot of buttons, which increment the counter. I need the counter all the way up in the main component, so I want to pass the `Counter` value;

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import Card from "./Card";

const ProductList = (props) => {
    const products = props.products;
    const [ Counter, setCounter ] = useState(0);
    const Count = n => { setCounter(v => v + n) }

    return ( 
        <div className="ProductList" >
            {products.map((product) => (
                <Card product={product} key={product.id} C={Count} />))}
        </div>
    );
}

export default ProductList;
```

up to the parent component:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ProductList from "./ProductList";

const Products = () => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState (null);

    useEffect (() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/products')
            .then(res => {
                return res.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                setProducts(data);
            })
    }, []);
    
    return ( 
        <div className="ProductList">
            {products && <ProductList products={products}/>}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Products;
```

It's a simple question, but I'm not sure how it works. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the `Counter` reference in the `Products` component you should define it in the component itself and pass the function reference down to the child component.

Try to change your code like this:

`Products` component:

```
const Products = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState(null);
  const [Counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  
  const count = (n) => {
    setCounter((v) => v + n);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/products')
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setProducts(data);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='ProductList'>
      {products && <ProductList products={products} count={count}/>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Products;
```

`ProductList` component

```
import Card from "./Card";

const ProductList = (props) => {
    const products = props.products;
    const count = props.count
    
    return ( 
        <div className="ProductList" >
            {products.map((product) => (
                <Card product={product} key={product.id} C={count} />))}
        </div>
    );
}

export default ProductList;
```

However, if you need to pass the function down multiple levels, you should probably use the `Context API`, but from the question, I presume you just need to go down one level.

Comment: I need to go down multple levels so maybe I will try the Context API

Answer (score 1):

Define the counter state in the parent component then pass both the counter and setCounter to the child as props. Update counter with setCounter and it will be update in the parent component also.

Child:

```
import Card from "./Card";

const ProductList = ({counter, setCounter}) => {
    const products = props.products;
    const Count = n => { setCounter(v => v + n) }

    return ( 
        <div className="ProductList" >
            {products.map((product) => (
                <Card product={product} key={product.id} C={Count} />))}
        </div>
    );
}

export default ProductList;
```

Parent:

```
import ProductList from "./ProductList";

const Products = () => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState (null);
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

    useEffect (() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/products')
            .then(res => {
                return res.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                setProducts(data);
            })
    }, []);
    
    return ( 
        <div className="ProductList">
            {products && 
         <ProductList 
             counter={counter} 
             setCounter={setCounter}
             products={products}
        />}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Products;
```

Comment: ok but I need to do it one more time to the main component which is above the mentioned parent component, so can I just define it in the main component and pass it down sa prop two levels dwon, will it work that way?

Comment: Yes it will work. Watch out tho,  when it gets too nested you tend to get confused. That's when you look into state management systems like redux. Or context api

Comment: See also [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) for a more elaborate explanation.